# Image retrieval function for jquery datatable in asp.net mvc is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find a proper solution for my ASP.NET MVC Project. I am showing my data inside the jquery datatable via json. But I cannot show image. ImagePath comes in place of image. I tried to render a function inside the "data" : "employee_image" but it is not working.

Here is my Json data,

```js
 var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
           

          dataTable = $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/employee/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",
                     
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "employee_name" },
                    { "data": "employee_father_name" },
                    { "data": "employee_mother_name" },
                    {
                        "data": "employee_DOB", "render": function (value) {
                            if (value === null) return "";

                            var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                            var results = pattern.exec(value);
                            var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

                            return (dt.getDate()) + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
                        } },
                    { "data": "employee_gender" },
                    { "data": "employee_mobile" },
                    { "data": "employee_email" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<img src="~/Images/Employee/' + row.employee_image + '"/>';
                        }
                    },
                       
                    
                    {
                        "data": "employee_create_date", "render": function (value) {
                            if (value === null) return "";

                            var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                            var results = pattern.exec(value);
                            var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

                            return dt.getDate() + "-" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
                        } },

                    {
                        "data": "employee_id", "render": function (data)
                        {
                            return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick = PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit", "Employee")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick = Delete(" + data + ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
                        },

                        "orderable": false,
                        
                         "width": "150px"
                     },


                ]
                
            });
            
        });
```